# Colspan not working as expected, only spans one column

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

My colspan is being set correctly but isnt working, acting as if it is not there, see below:

[image]

Ive no real idea as to why this is happening or how to fix, could my CSS for the table be stopping it from operating correctly?

Code where colspan is set:

```
<div class="fixedTable fullwidth" id="demo">
    <header class="fixedTable-header">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>

                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.SupervisorAndProjects.Count(); j++)
                {
                    string background = Model.AssignedArray[j]%2 == 0 ? "background-color:#7BD2ED" : "background-color:#74C3DB";
                    string text = "color:#ffffff";
                    <th style="text-align: center; @background; @text" colspan="@Model.SupervisorAndProjects[j].NumberOfProjects">@Model.SupervisorAndProjects[j].SupervisorProjects (@Model.SupervisorAndProjects[j].MaxLoad/@Model.SupervisorAndProjects[j].NumberOfProjects)</th>
                }
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </header>
```

Here is my CSS for the table:

```
.fixedTable .table {
 background-color: white;
 width: auto;
}
.fixedTable .table tr td,
.fixedTable .table tr th {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fixedTable-header {
  width: 87.5%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.fixedTable-sidebar {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 95%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.fixedTable-body {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 87.5%;
  height: 95%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: does you table header and table boy in diffrent table?

Comment: They are yes, is is to ensure they are froze/fixed at the top when scrolling

Comment: Fixed cell(th and td) width, when th is colspan then multiple spreading its width. for example : normal width is 80px, if th cross 3 td then set its width is 240px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you have split out the tables, you need to make sure it's all part of the same table for the colspan to be effective.

Comment: You are correct, there are four tables, 3 of which (the top two rows and the first column) need to be separate in order to freeze/fix them in place.  The last table is the rest.  Is there no way of having acolspan if they are separate?

Comment: I see your problem. You may be better adding width classes on the th elements. e.g. .colspan-2: (double your cell width in pixels). you'll need to use table-layout: fixed on both table elements though, and just use one th per header. Alternatively, a javascript solution where the widths are calculated based on the below table.

Comment: @Spitfire5793 did you manage to get it to work? Hope this was useful.

Comment: Yes I got it working, used classes in the end which set the width.  Thanks for the help.